Two vite versions in one NPM package
This is a link to a project I forked
[https://github.com/guruyaya/vite5-plugin-replace]
If you look at the changes, the main differance is, in the code is, in package.json, where I replaced:
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2"
  }

with:
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vite": "^5"
  }

The thing is, I would like to offer this as a real fix to the NPM package. My tests show this plugin works, with no issues on version 5, and as for version 2 - my guess it was allready tested by it's owner. However, I have no intention of suggesting this fix, without allowing it to work on both version 2 and version 5. I could not find, however, a way to allow 2 different versions of vite. Can you help me with this?
Thanks

There is no tests in the project, either in your fork or the original repository. The project is not tested.

You can use the logical OR operator for that purpose: ^2 || ^5
